# Angular4, Simple post for upload video, Vimeo API,

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface, vimeo-api

I have a single page web app build in Angular v4 as a CMS for Vimeo, I have post of thumbnails working and editing of meta data but cannot solve the video upload with the simple post method as described in the API.

I'm calling 'getUploadTicket' in ngOnInit and displaying upload_secure_link in DOM, so I know that is there, then function 'uploadPostMethod' below is called on a submit button in the HTML, the file is defined with 'fileChangeEvent'

```
getUploadTicket(): Promise<Video> {
return this.http.post('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos' + this.token, this.headersX)
.toPromise()
.then(response => response.json() as Video)
.catch(this.handleErrorPromise);
}

fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
this.filesToUpload = fileInput.target.files;
let file: File = this.filesToUpload[0];
}

uploadPostMethod(url): any {
let file: File = this.filesToUpload[0];
console.log(JSON.stringify(url));
return this.http.post(url,file,this.headersPost)
  .map((response) => {
    let data = response.text() ? response.json() : [{}];
    if (data) {
      console.log('returned after post video file to upload' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  })
```

}

my html is :

```
    {{video.uri}}<br>
    {{video.upload_link_secure}}<br>
    {{video.ticket_id}}<br>
    {{video.form}}<br>


    <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Select file" accept="video/mp4"/>
    <br><br>
    <button style="width: 100%" class="mdl-button" (click)="uploadPostMethod(video.upload_link_secure)">Upload Video</button>
```

But i'm just not getting any resolve with uploading - the file size is small at 966469bytes, any help or syntax points in angular would be very much appreciated. I'm not using any vimeo libraries. - I have had some success in postman once I deleted the redirecturl paramater from the upload_secure_link but now that is failing - access token is valid and works.
(angular 4, CLI, Vimeo API)